# Can't print or stop print job

Tags: printing

I use a Huawei Mate 10 Pro. I am unable to print, so I tried to cancel the printing
job, but it just stays there forever and nothing happens.

I was unable to print a single page since I own this smartphone which I bought a year ago. The only way to remove it is by restarting the smartphone.

I am using a Canon MG 3200 printer.

PS: "notepad print wird gelöscht" means "notepad print is getting deleted" in english

[image]

Comment: The question does not focus on both the router/printer and rather on your phone. Can you try printing with another phone?

Comment: @CaldeiraG, ok thx, I flagged it. Yes I tried with Huawei P20 Pro, but it failed too.